# Gaussian beam shape

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

In this diagram of a Gaussian beam, why does the radius vary with z position? Is it assumed that a Gaussian beam is always being focus by a lense? Why can the beam not go any smaller than $w_0$ and how is $w_0$ calculated?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A Gaussian beam has a width that changes with distance because of [diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction), which is an effect that takes place in any wave phenomenon.  It has a pretty similar description to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in QM if you're familiar with that.  Namely, as the position in the $x$ and $y$ directions (with the optical axis pointing in the $z$ direction) becomes very well defined, the spatial frequencies (basically the same thing as momentum) in the $x$ and $y$ directions become very ill-defined.  This means the tighter you focus a beam, the more it will tend to spread.  So if you do anything to try to converge a Gaussian beam to a point, diffraction will compete against you and you're left with some non-zero smallest spot size.

It doesn't have anything to do with the specifics of how you make the beam narrower (e.g. lensing), but is just a consequence of wave optics.  If you'd like to see the math behind this, take a look at the [paraxial wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Paraxial_approximation) which describes waves mostly travelling in 1 direction, such as a Gaussian beam in the $z$ direction.  You'll find there are no solutions to that equation with zero beam width except for the trivial solution where the amplitude is zero everywhere.